# How to make react-admin default theme RTL

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I need to make react-admin which uses material-ui underneath into RTL, so far nothing works because there are styles on each element overriding `dir="rtl"` on body tag, creating a custom theme like:

```
const theme = {
  direction: 'rtl',
  isRtl: true
};
const themeWithDirection = createMuiTheme({...defaultTheme, ...theme});
```

and using it on Admin component like:

```
<Admin locale="ar" dataProvider={dataProvider} i18nProvider={i18nProvider} theme={themeWithDirection} layout={layout}>
```

did not work. also usign `StyleProvider` on custom layout did not work:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Layout } from 'react-admin';

import { create } from 'jss';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import {  jssPreset } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const jss = create({ plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()] });

const MyLayout = props => 
  <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
    <Layout
      {...props}
    />
  </StylesProvider>;
```

The problem is that components like `TextField` use `text-align: left;`, so how can I flip their css without overriding them in a custom css file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `ListGuesser` I had no luck switching the grid to RTL, however, after writing a custom list component and JssProvider it now works:

```
import React from 'react';
import { List, Datagrid, TextField, EmailField } from 'react-admin';

import { create } from 'jss';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import { jssPreset } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


const jss = create({ plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()] });

export const UserList = props => (
  <JssProvider jss={jss}>
    <List {...props}>
      <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
        <TextField source="id" />
        <TextField source="name" />
        <TextField source="username" />
        <EmailField source="email" />
        <TextField source="address.street" />
        <TextField source="phone" />
        <TextField source="website" />
        <TextField source="company.name" />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  </JssProvider>
);
```